# Redirect grep error output to file

Tags: grep, output, stderr

I wanted to capture to a file the errors being returned on the command line from `grep`. For example,

```
grep foo.lookup
No such file in directory
```

I want to output that to a log file. This is my shell script:

```
lookUpVal=1
var1=$(grep $lookUpVal foo.lookup) >>lookup.log 2>$1
```

It creates the file `lookup.log` but doesn't write the error on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correct, you want to capture the output of `grep` into a variable and append any error to the logfile.

You could say:

```
var1=$(grep $lookUpVal foo.lookup 2>>lookup.log)
```

The `$(...)` syntax denotes command substitution, i.e. outputs the result of the command into a variable.  By default it would capture the `STDOUT` of the command into the variable and the `STDERR` is printed to the console.  In order to redirect the `STDERR` to a file, you would need to perform the redirection within the command itself, i.e. within `$(...)`.

Comment: devnull, thank you! you're the best. thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

`grep foo.lookup` isn't a correct example. It's missing an argument, either a search parameter or a filename.

To capture just the error messages that `grep` returns to a file you could do this:

```
$ grep $lookUpVal foo.lookup 2> errors.log
```

All errors are sent to STDERR (`2>`) while all output is sent to STDOUT (`1>`). They're combined like this:

```
$ grep $lookUpVal foo.lookup > output.log 2>&1
```

Comment: grep foo.lookup is the error message. I want that to be printed in the file. The grep is part of the shell script. It has to return a value to a variable.