# Capture Error of LS to file

Tags: shell, shell-script, files, io-redirection

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $(ls sample01.log | wc -l) = 1 ]
then
echo "File Found" > lsOutput.log
else
echo "File Not Found" > lsOutput.log
fi
```

But if sample01.log is not already existing my code already returns the error:

```
ls: cannot access sample01.log: No such file or directory
```

And the code will not run anymore. The File Not Found will not be displayed anymore. I wanted to capture that error to file (No such file or directory) so each time such error occurs, it is written and documented on the log file.

Thank you.

Comment: Your two questions are basically the same. The answer to both question titles is the same: use `2>>logfile` inside the parenthesis.  I think we should merge the two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to parse `ls` in order to determine if a file exists.

`help test` would tell you:

```
  -e FILE        True if file exists.
```

You could say:

```
if [ -e sample01.log ]
then
  echo "File Found" > lsOutput.log
else
  echo "File Not Found" > lsOutput.log
fi
```

If you want to ensure that the file is a regular file, use `-f` instead:

```
  -f FILE        True if file exists and is a regular file.
```

(What you've done also works, but it causes `ls` to emit an error message (to `STDERR`) which perhaps leads you into thinking that it doesn't work.)

Comment: Hi devnull. Thank you very much. This forum really helped me in my wanting to learn shell scripting more. It worked!

Comment: Would you also know if I can capture grep errors into file? My question is posted in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117603/redirect-grep-error-output-to-file

Comment: @user60216 Note that `[` is actually other name for to `test`.  So also `if test -f myfile; then ...` would work but also `test -f myfile && do_something_to myfile` is pretty common.